# Parsing a JSON string (or is it XML?)

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have an XML file I need to pass.

http://mckay.canvashost.com:8080/opentripplanner-api-webapp/ws/transit/stopTimesForStop?id=27833&startTime=1361784386000&extended=true&references=true

I used PHP's CURL to load it into the page:

```
$url = "http://mckay.canvashost.com:8080/opentripplanner-api-webapp/ws/transit/stopTimesForStop?id=27833&startTime=1361784386000&extended=true&references=true";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
echo htmlentities($xml, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

The output is a JSON file, which I wasn't expecting.  No matter, I continued working with the JSON but can't seem to parse it.

I had thought this would work:

```
$obj=json_decode($xml);
echo $obj[stopTime][0][phase];
```

With a result of 'departure'.  I've spent a good while on this yet can't get it to output anything.

Anyone help?  And anyone know at which point it switched from an XML file to JSON format?

Comment: What are you trying to extract out of this data?

Comment: Try `json_decode($xml,true);`. [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: That link returns an XML file for me. What makes you think it is JSON?

Comment: the link does indeed return an XML file but the echo htmlentities($xml, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); gives an output in JSON

Comment: The output is not json. You are outputting

Comment: I did try    $obj=json_decode($xml,true);   but got the same thing.  I am trying to extract things like routeLongName which is an attribute in the XML   In the JSON (which is outputted on the echo htmlentities($xml, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); line) , it appears under just longName (I have no idea why it does that).  Am I the only one seeing JSON??

Comment: @alexrichardson I can't open your link (possibly due to company restriction), but an entitie-d XML can not become a JSON. Can you please post the origin and entitie-d TEXT sample for us to see?

Comment: @Passerby there shouldn't be any restrictions on the link, but I've pasted the XML here [link]http://pastebin.com/AREFvVZf and the  echo htmlentities etc. line outputs this [link]http://pastebin.com/3g0kuK37

Comment: @alexrichardson I meant _my company_ restricted that :) Anyway, your XML doesn't seem to have (logically) the same structure with your JSON, and I don't seem to be able to `htmlentities` your XML into your JSON. I suggest you directly use DOM or simpleXML to parse `$xml` and see if there's any error.

Comment: It's odd, right?  I'll try simpleXML again as it is enabled (although I couldn't get that working either...).  Turning into quite a problem bit of code :)

Answer (score 0):

the output is a xml-string.
try to use php's xml functionality delivered by SimpleXml:

[SimpleXml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

as soon as you successfully parsed the string you can iterate its nodes like an array

```
foreach ($xmlElement as $node) {
echo $node->attributeName;
}
```